# Longest increasing subsequence with maximum sum plus constraint - allowed number of elements can be skipped

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

The longest increasing sub-sequence with maximum sum (http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-14-maximum-sum-increasing-subsequence/) is a classic algorithm problem and there exist a lot of solutions on the web. However, I just encountered a variation of this problem and have no idea how to solve it.

Compared with the original question, now you are also given a number m which indicates the number of elements you can skip at most from a continuous sub-range in order to find the LIS with maximum sum. For example, with the following array,

[1, 200, 300, 3, 4, 5, 6]

The LIS is 1,3,4,5,6 and the maximum sum is 19. However, if m is 1, it means that at most one element can be skipped in a continuous sub-range in order to find the LIS. Hence the above solution is not right because between 1 and 3, two elements are skipped (200, 300 in this case).  The new solution should be 3,4,5,6 since no elements are skipped in a continuous sub-range. The question is to find the LIS with the maximum sum and return the sub-sequence (not the sum or the length of the sub-sequence) when the array and the number m is given. I have been stuck with this problem for several days so any help is appreciated.

Edit: O(n^2) solution is good enough for now since I have complete no idea where to start.

Edit: m is the cumulative steps can be skipped for the entire array, not the steps can be skipped between two separate increasing sub-sequence.

Comment: BTW, the original LIS problem can be solved in O(n^2) or O(nlgn). For this question, even a O(n^2) solution is good for me.

Comment: Is O(n^2 log n) ok?

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by using Dynamic programming technique.

Call the input array `data` length `n`.

Assume we have an array `dp[n][n + 1]` which entry `dp[i][j]` store the nearest index, which from `i` to `dp[i][j]`, the length of increasing sub-sequence start at `i` is `j`. If we have this `dp`, the result for your question is straight forwards.

Now, how to calculate `dp[i][j]` for a specific `j`? moving `i` backward from index `n - 1` to `0`, assume that, we maintain another array `list[n + 1]`, with `list[i]` storing all index `k`, which has a increasing sub-sequence start at `k` and length `i`. We need to maintain the property of `list[j]`: `list[j]` is decreasing list, with element at index `x` and `y` in `list[j]`, then `data[x] > data[y]` if and only if `x < y`. If we have `list[j]` for each length `j`, for `dp[i][j + 1]`, we only need to binary search inside `list[j]` to find the smallest element in list[j] which is greater than data[i].

```
int[][]dp = new int[n][n + 1];
fill(dp, -1);
List<Integer>[]lists = new List[n + 1];
for(int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++){
        if(j == 1){
            dp[i][j] = i;

        }else if(!list[j - 1].isEmpty()){
            int index = binary search in list[j - 1] to get the nearest index that greater than data[i];
            dp[i][j] = dp[index][j - 1];

        }
        if(dp[i][j] == -1)
           continue;
        while(data[list[j].peekLast()] <= data[i]){
        //Remove all entries which is smaller than i in list, we can easily see that all entries which is smaller than i can only end at point at least as near as end point of i.
           list[j].pollLast();
        }
        if(list[j].isEmpty() || dp[list[j].peekLast()][j] > dp[i][j]){
        //Only add entry to list if result of new entry is nearer. 
           list[j].add(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Time complexity **O(n^2 logn)**.

Comment: I am not sure I quite get you. You mentioned that: If we have this dp, the result for your question is straight forwards. I am not sure how to get the results if this dp is built. One more example, if the input array is [1,200,300, 4, 100, 50, 5, 6, 7, 8] and m is 1, the result is [5,6,7,8]. If m is 2, the result is [4,5,6,7,8] and if m is 4, the result is [1,4,5,6,7,8]. Can your algorithm get this answer?

Comment: @OptimusPrime with that input array, so, for index 0, dp[0][1] = 0, dp[0][2] = 1, dp[0][3] = 2, dp[0][4] = 7, dp[0][5] = 8. For sequence starts from 0 and have length 3, so it will start from 0 and end at dp[0][3]. So the number of characters that need to be removed is 0. If we need a sequence start from 0 and has length 4, the number of characters need to be removed is (dp[0][4] - 0 + 1) - 4 =  3. Basically, with `dp`, we know the length of the segment and the length of increasing sequence in that segment, to calculate how many character need to be removed is trivial.